# Sql server 2012 fetch vs old row_number performance. What am I missing? Why is row_number 17x faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

**Update:** Infact leave the below complicated query and please check this query. It says Fetch is 98% as compared to 2% in Row_Number?

[image]

Is Fetch yet another marketing keyword for sql server 2012?

-------------------------Original question--------------------

Let me clear that wherever I read, I find it stating that Fetch is very fast than old Row_Number function. However, I find it nearly the opposite and by a *long* way. My DB has nearly 0.2 million records. This is my query using Fetch:

```
exec sp_executesql N'set arithabort off;set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
                                    Select cte.DocumentID, cte.IsReEfiled, cte.IGroupID, cte.ITypeID, cte.RecordingDateTime, cte.CreatedByAccountID, cte.JurisdictionID, 
                        cte.LastStatusChangedDateTime as LastStatusChangedDateTime
                        ,  cte.IDate, cte.InstrumentID, cte.DocumentStatusID,ig.Abbreviation as IGroupAbbreviation, u.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName,
                       it.Abbreviation, cte.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation,  ds.Name as DocumentStatusName,
                        ( SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN cte.DocumentID = (
                                SELECT TOP 1 doc.DocumentID
                                FROM  Documents doc
                                WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID
                                        AND doc.DocumentStatusID = cte.DocumentStatusID
                                ORDER BY LastStatusChangedDateTime) 
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END AS BIT)
                        ) AS CanChangeStatus ,

                        Upper((Select Top 1 Stuff( (Select ''='' + dbo.GetDocumentNameFromParamsWithPartyType(Business, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, t.Abbreviation, NameTypeID, pt.Abbreviation, IsGrantor, IsGrantee)  From DocumentNames dn
                                Left Join Titles t
                                    on dn.TitleID = t.TitleID               
                                Left Join PartyTypes pt
                                    On pt.PartyTypeID = dn.PartyTypeID
                                        Where DocumentID = cte.DocumentID
                                            For XML PATH('''')),1,1,''''))) as FlatDocumentName 

                        FROM Documents cte Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On                     
                        cte.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID 
                        Inner Join Users u on cte.UserID = u.UserID
                        Inner Join IGroupes ig On ig.IGroupID = cte.IGroupID
                        Inner Join ITypes it On ig.IGroupID = it.IGroupID
                        Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On cte.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                    Left Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID Where 1=1
                    Order by cte.LastStatusChangedDateTime OFFSET 110700 Rows FETCH Next 50 Rows ONLY',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 int,@8 int,@9 int,@10 int,@11 int',
                    @0=4,@1=1,@2=5,@3=9,@4=4,@5=1,@6=1,@7=5,@8=9,@9=4,@10=1,@11=1
```

The above query takes 17 seconds to produce 50 records. This is the query plan:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the query plan XML in case it's not clear from images:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/br5urj4xapazu9l/fetch.txt

Now this is the same query using old Row_Number (and using the same DB indexes and columns and Joins as Fetch):

```
exec sp_executesql N'set arithabort off;set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;With cte as (Select peta_rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  d.LastStatusChangedDateTime  asc )  
                                                , d.DocumentID
                                                , u.Username
                                                , it.Abbreviation AS ITypeAbbreviation
                                                , ig.Abbreviation AS IGroupAbbreviation
                                                , d.IsReEfiled 
                                                , d.IGroupID 
                                                , d.ITypeID 
                                                , d.RecordingDateTime 
                                                , d.CreatedByAccountID 
                                                , d.JurisdictionID
                                                , d.LastStatusChangedDateTime AS LastStatusChangedDateTime 
                                                , d.IDate 
                                                , d.InstrumentID 
                                                , d.DocumentStatusID
                                                , d.DocumentDate
                                From Documents d
                                Inner Join Users u on d.UserID = u.UserID Inner Join IGroupes ig on ig.IGroupID = d.IGroupID
                                Inner Join ITypes it on it.ITypeID = d.ITypeID Where 1=1  ANd d.IGroupID = @0   And (d.JurisdictionID = @1 Or DocumentStatusID = @2 Or DocumentStatusID = @3
                                    Or DocumentStatusID = @4 Or DocumentStatusID = @5)   And d.DocumentStatusID <> 3 And  d.DocumentStatusID <> 8 And  d.DocumentStatusID <> 7 AND
                                        ((CreatedByJurisdictionID = @6 Or DocumentStatusID = @7 Or DocumentStatusID = @8
                                        Or DocumentStatusID = @9 Or DocumentStatusID = @10
                                    Or CreatedByAccountID IN (Select AccountID From AccountsJurisdictions Where JurisdictionID = @11)))) Select cte.DocumentID, cte.IsReEfiled, cte.IGroupID, cte.ITypeID, cte.RecordingDateTime, cte.CreatedByAccountID, cte.JurisdictionID, 
                        cte.LastStatusChangedDateTime as LastStatusChangedDateTime
                        ,  cte.IDate, cte.InstrumentID, cte.DocumentStatusID,cte.IGroupAbbreviation, cte.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName,
                       cte.ITypeAbbreviation, cte.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation,  ds.Name as DocumentStatusName,
                        ( SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN cte.DocumentID = (
                                SELECT TOP 1 doc.DocumentID
                                FROM  Documents doc
                                WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID
                                        AND doc.DocumentStatusID = cte.DocumentStatusID
                                ORDER BY LastStatusChangedDateTime) 
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END AS BIT)
                        ) AS CanChangeStatus ,

                        Upper((Select Top 1 Stuff( (Select ''='' + dbo.GetDocumentNameFromParamsWithPartyType(Business, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, t.Abbreviation, NameTypeID, pt.Abbreviation, IsGrantor, IsGrantee)  From DocumentNames dn
                                Left Join Titles t
                                    on dn.TitleID = t.TitleID               
                                Left Join PartyTypes pt
                                    On pt.PartyTypeID = dn.PartyTypeID
                                        Where DocumentID = cte.DocumentID
                                            For XML PATH('''')),1,1,''''))) as FlatDocumentName 

                        FROM cte Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On
                        cte.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On cte.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                    Left Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID Where 1=1 And peta_rn>@12 AND peta_rn<=@13 Order by peta_rn',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 int,@8 int,@9 int,@10 int,@11 int,@12 int,@13 int',@0=4,@1=1,@2=5,@3=9,@4=4,@5=1,@6=1,@7=5,@8=9,@9=4,@10=1,@11=1,@12=110700,@13=110750
```

This query takes less than 1 second! This is the query plan for that:
[image]

[image]

[image]

So, what am I missing? Why is row_number faster than Fetch?

This is the query plan for rownum:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uin66esfb2ov8m7/rownum.txt

Comment: All I can see is FETCH for some reason does not use the index by LastStatusChangDateTime. Can you try to run the query with FETCH and the INDEX HINT to see if it is faster

Comment: @chacha: Still doesn't make any difference. Please see this link: http://gyazo.com/e054dca0fcf4f42277137086de6d3c2a

Comment: Regarding your first (simpler) example the `OFFSET` may well be more efficient despite what the costs say. The costs shown are based on estimates even in the actual plan. What is the estimated number of executions of the key lookup and the actual in the second plan? If you do `SET STATISTICS IO ON; SET STATISTICS TIME ON` which looks better? Regarding your actual query please supply the *.sqlplan XML not just the images.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I've posted the link for both query plans above as I was unable to post the query plan here due to body limit of 30K characters. Please let me know if anything else is missing.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is not OFFSET/FETCH vs ROW_NUMBER

in your original question the two queries are **NOT** the same,

the first query (OFFSET/FETCH) misses all filtering conditions on parameters, so it works on a larger base data and, with many JOINS the number of records could grows quickly

in second query (ROW_NUMBER) left joins are applyed after CTE execution and only for matching records (peta_rn>@12 AND peta_rn<=@13) reducing very much number of records to join.

the two queries are not comparable at all, I think that if you write the CTE version, using OFFSET/FETCH it will be faster than ROW_NUMBER version.

in fact talking about your **EDIT/UPDATE**, do not consider what EXECUTION PLAN tells you, just execute both and measure timings.. You will find that OFFSET/FETCH is faster anyway.

**2018-10-04 EDIT/UPDATE**
I did some more testing on differents scenarios and I found out that results can be different depending on indexes and table cardinality (aka `COUNT(*)`)

If you are ordering by a column with a clustered index `OFFSET/FETCH` will be much faster than `ROW_NUMBER`. 
On little tables (less than 20000 rows) execution time is almost the same but with large tables `OFFSET/FETCH` will become soon much faster (200-300%).

If you are ordering by a column with a non clustered index, `OFFSET/FETCH` is never worst than `ROW_NUMBER` but the latter can perform well depending on parameters (table rows count, starting record and number of rows fetched).

If you are ordering by a column without any index `OFFSET/FETCH` is still a little faster than `ROW_NUMBER` but they perform almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2696/comparing-performance-for-different-sql-server-paging-methods/
Fetch works best for 2012 according to the above...